# Removing next/previous links on first & last posts in Staceyapp V.3 with Twig

Tags: php, twig

I am using Stacey V.3 app for a small site of mine. On my blog posts I would like to have a previous and next link to navigate through different posts. Easy. What I would like to do now is on my last post remove the 'next' link which would essentially be a link to the very first post of my collection.

I research and have tried using this snippet which doesn't work.

```
{% for sibling in page.siblings %}
{% if loop.first %}
        Nothing should be generated
            {% else %}
        {% include 'partials/next-page.html' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

My knowledge of Twig and PHP could be written on the head of a pin. So, i'll be honest with you. I am trying to do something like this

{if the current post is last dont show a previous link}
{if the current post is first dont show a next link}

{else}

{show a next and previous link on every post}

Please don't shoot me as i'm a 'NUBE'

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `Next project` link from the last project page:

Replace the contents of templates/partials/next-page.html with:

```
{% if page.is_last %}
<p>&nbsp;</p>
{% else %}
{% for sibling in page.next_sibling %}
<p><a href="{{ sibling.url }}">Next project</a>: &rarr; {{ sibling.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

And

To remove the `Previous project` link from the first project page:

Replace the contents of templates/partials/previous-page.html with:

```
{% if page.is_first %}
<p>&nbsp;</p>
{% else %}
{% for sibling in page.previous_sibling %}
<p><a href="{{ sibling.url }}">Previous project</a>: &larr; {{ sibling.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```